# semantic ui grid - display full width of column, after "computer only" columns is hidden

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css

For computer sized screen I have an additional column on the left to display some optional content. When the screen size goes under the breaking point of 991px, that column hides using semantic-ui's native css classes.
In this case the column with the main content should display in full width.
I was wondering if there is a "native" semantic-ui way of achieving this?

```
<div class="ui grid container">
    <div class="four wide computer only column">
        (Optional content only for computers sized screen)
    </div>
    <div class="twelve wide column">
        (Main Content)
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to do something like:

```
<div class="sixteen wide tablet column twelve wide computer column">
    (Main Content)
</div>
```