# semantic-ui-react grid - display full width of column, after "only” columns is hidden

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I would like to know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823381/semantic-ui-grid-display-full-width-of-column-after-computer-only-columns-i) same technique is possible in semantic-ui-react? I would like the main content grid column to go full width in cases when the optional column is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same code as in the accepted answer:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Column computer={4} only='computer'>
    (Optional content only for computers sized screen)
  </Grid.Column>
  <Grid.Column tablet={16} computer={12}>
    (Main Content)
  </Grid.Column>
</Grid>
```

See [device visibility](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid#grid-example-only) and [responsive width](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid#grid-example-responsive-width) sections of docs.